# How do I add a jar to SBT's classpath?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I have a Java [Play](https://www.playframework.com/) project and I added [Snake Yaml](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml) to my class path.

`libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.yaml" % "snakeyaml" % "1.16")`

This works great, my app can import `org.yaml`.

However, SBT cannot import `org.yaml`. It does not have access to `libraryDependencies` for some reason.

If I add `import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml` to `project/commons.scala`, I get an error when I compile with `activator compile`.

```
[error] <path to project>/project/commons.scala:2: object yaml is not a member of package org
[error] import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

How do I get make jars accessible within SBT?

Comment: Did you `reload` after adding the JAR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a dependency X to the source code of the project is not the same as adding a dependency X to your build code (a dependency to be used inside `build.sbt`, `project/*.scala`, etc.)

If that is what you are trying to do then you need to add the library dependency inside your project folder.

For example, just add `libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.yaml" % "snakeyaml" % "1.16")` inside `project/build.sbt` (in contrast to adding in the normal `./build.sbt` file).

#### Minimal project that showcase this

Structure:

```
.
├── build.sbt
└── project
    └── build.sbt
```

**build.sbt**

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

name := "hello"
```

**project/build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.yaml" % "snakeyaml" % "1.16")
```

Comment: Another example of this can be found http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Plugins.html